# Finding a mininal parameters of distance in equation (C)

Tags: c, algorithm, parameters, equation

I need to write a function that gets a neutral n that bigger then 7. the function calculting the equation 3x+5y = n and prints the value of x and y, but if there are more then one answer, it should check which one of them as the minimal absoult value (|x-y|), and print it. 
(for example, if the n is 34 then the two results are (3,5) and (8,2) but it would print (3,5).

So, I could easly write down a program with 2 for loops and check x and y one by one until i get a result, then compare the results.. but it won't be effective. I feel that there is a better way but I couldn't find it. 
my toughts were about using mod maybe, but I couldn't develope it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c

Comment: Start  by posting the program that you could easily write down.  Doing so adds clarity to your goal and serves as a base line for performance testing.

Comment: Did you ever take geometry when in school?  The answer to your question is very simple when using the equations taught in geometry.

Comment: what is a ??mininal??  what is meant by a ??neutral n??  what is meant by ??absoult??   Please use your spell checker, so we are not guessing as to your meaning.